# Pass struct by reference in C, but modifications aren't all there

Tags: c, arrays, struct, pass-by-reference, configuration-files

I am trying to make a simple program to read a config file in C. But the data in my struct members isn't staying where I put it.

Code at the bottom.

This is what I *think* I am doing:

- I am creating a struct that
- Passing the struct by reference
- Populating the members of the struct from the config file

When I try to access the members, I can only get the data from the last row in the config file.

Thanks!

---

Edit: I expected it to populate the struct with key / values from the config file. Instead it only had the value of the last line in the config file.

**expected output**

`example.com`

**actual output**

`food.txt`

Problem is with:

```
conf->key[i]   = key;
conf->value[i] = value;
```

**main.c**

```
/*
* Goal is to make simple key value storage with struct and pointers
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 100
#define CONFIG_MAX_BUF 1024
#define DELIM "="

struct config_s {
    char *key[MAXLEN];
    char *value[MAXLEN];
};

void read_config_file(struct config_s *conf, char *filename, int *size_of_array);

int main() {
    int i = 0, size_of_array;
    // type config_s has key and value members
    struct config_s c;

    read_config_file(&c, "test.cfg", &size_of_array);
    printf("size of array: %i\n", size_of_array);

    // if i want to print them all out, i can use this, but i'll have 
    // a function to search for a certain key and return the value.
    int l = 0, e = 1;
    printf("********** TEST 1 ***********\n");
    printf("key: [%s] value: [%s] i: [%i]\n", c.key[l], c.value[l], l);
    printf("key: [%s] value: [%s] i: [%i]\n", c.key[e], c.value[e], e);
    printf("********** TEST 2 ***********\n");

    return 0;
}

void read_config_file(struct config_s *conf, char *filename, int *size_of_array) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    char line[CONFIG_MAX_BUF];

    int i = 0;

    char *cfline;
    char *key;
    char *value;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
        cfline = strstr((char *)line, DELIM);
        value = cfline + strlen(DELIM);
        value[strlen(value) - 1] = '\0';

        key = strtok((char *)line, DELIM);
        printf("%i %s %s\n", i, key, value);
        conf->key[i]   = key;
        conf->value[i] = value;
        printf("%i %s %s\n", i, (*conf).key[i], (*conf).value[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s %s\n", (*conf).key[0], (*conf).value[0]);
    fclose(file);
    *size_of_array = i;
    return;
}
```

**test.cfg**

```
server=example.com
port=443
file=food.txt
```

Comment: That's because you're assigning pointers, not strings.

Comment: `Pass struct by reference in C`, BUT there is no *pass by reference* mechanism in **C**! C only has *pass by value* mechanism

Comment: You are not passing by reference, because C does not support that.  You are passing a pointer to the struct.  Using the proper terminology IS important.

Comment: @CherubimAnand: Strictly speaking, yes. On the other hand, it's not unreasonable to say that you can *implement* (the equivalent of) pass-by-reference in C using pointers. Similarly, C doesn't have linked lists, but you can implement them using structures and pointers; nobody would claim that such an implementation isn't *really* a linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your newest version of `read_config_file`, you're saving pointers to the values that point *within* the buffer `line`, which is on the *stack*, so these pointers will be invalid upon return.

Even if the buffer were global, the pointers would be colliding with one another for each line because the buffer gets overwritten with each `fgets` call.

Change:

```
conf->key[i]   = key;
conf->value[i] = value;
```

Into:

```
conf->key[i]   = strdup(key);
conf->value[i] = strdup(value);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning.

Comment: You're welcome! I've been writing in C for [quite] a while, but I _still_ create a least one bug per day. We're _all_ still learning ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There maybe more than one issue in your code. I can see one of them in `get_value_by_key` function. Here you are comparing `conf->key[i]` with `key` which will never be true (Because you are comparing two different pointers). Instead what you want to do is:

```
if(strncmp(conf->key[i], key, strlen(conf->key[i])+1) == 0)
```

to compare the two strings to which these two pointers are pointing.

```
char *get_value_by_key(config_s *conf, char *key, int config_size) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<config_size;i++) {
        /*if(conf->key[i] == key) {*/ //Instead of this
        /* Do this */
         if(strncmp(conf->key[i], key, strlen(conf->key[i])+1) == 0) {
            return conf->value[i];
         }
    }
    /* Also return NULL if there is no match */
    return NULL;
}
```